# Use function mle2() in bbmle package(R) to get parameters for exponential and power law distribution

Tags: r, exponential, mle, power-law

Here is a part of mydata:

The raw data is very big, so I upload a part of it with 20 rows.

```
x <- [7.6,2.2,1.1,4.7,8.6,7.5,7.5,29.9,5.0,3.0,2.4,1.5,14.9,3.9,3.7,3.2,5.0,1.7,2.9,2.3]
```

Here is function description

1. power law: `y=A*x^-(u)`
2. exponential: `y=B*exp^(-βx)`

Now, I want to use MLE(Maximum likelihood method) to get `u` for power law, and `β` for exponential distribution.

```
#set likelihood function of power law
pl <- function(u){-n*log(u-1)-n*(u-1)*log(min(x))+u*sum(log(x))}

#set likelihood function of exponential distribution
ex <- function(β){-n*log(β)+β*sum(x)}
```

## Are these functions right?

Using mle2() to get the parameters:

```
#get the parameter u of power law
s1 <- mle2(pl,start = list(u=2),data = list(x))
summary(s1)
#get the parameter lamda of exponential distribution
s2 <- mle2(ex,start = list(β=2),data = list(x))
summary(s2)
```

Now here are two questions:

1. how to determine which one is the best to fit the model

   Using confint() could get the 95% CI, how do I get the Rsquared and AIC(Akaike weigths) of both model?
2. After I get which one is best to fit the data, How do I draw the fitted graph above the raw data?

I use R.3.2.2 in windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much as you might expect.   You haven't specified the conditional distribution of your data, so I'm going to assume Normality.  (Given this, you could also use `nls()` -- least-squares *is* maximum likelihood estimation for a Normal, homoscedastic response), although `mle2` offers a little more scope for playing with optimizers etc.)

I'm going to use the formula interface, which is convenient if your model isn't too complicated.

### power law

```
mle2(y~dnorm(mean=A*x^(-mu),sd=exp(logsd),
     start=list(A=...,mu=...,logsd=...),
     ## no need for list() if mydata is already data.frame
     data=mydata)
```

### exponential

```
  mle2(y~dnorm(mean=B*exp(-beta*x),sd=exp(logsd),
     start=list(B=...,beta=...,logsd=...),
     data=mydata)
```

... where the elements in `start` are any *reasonable* starting values.  Given your data above, these approaches ought to work reasonably on a subset of the data.  However, they might not perform well on 10 million observations.  I would consider using

```
glm(y~x,family=gaussian(link="log"),data=mydata)
```

to fit the exponential curve and

```
glm(y~log(x),family=gaussian(link="log"),data=mydata)
```

to fit the power-law curve.

Comment: x=[0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9]

Comment: x=[0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9], my data is something like that but the length of mydata is 10 million. And, one more question, A, mu and logsd  could be any number I input in the start list?

Comment: you might think mydata is data.frame with 2 columns named x and y?

Comment: could you please edit your question to include this information?

Comment: Sorry for my poor description of mydata, I have uploaded a part of mydata in the question description, please have an another look on it, Thx!

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear description of mydata, now I upload mydata into my question, please check it out, Thank you sincerely

Comment: I sent an email to your mailbox, please check it out. In the email, there are some ideas I want to share and discuss with you, Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't do off-line consultation.

Comment: Never Mind. Another question, how to get Rsquare, AIC(Akaike weight) for both model, I want to know which model is best to fit mydata, and I know function confint() to get 95% CI

Comment: Sir, I have updated my questions more clearly, please take an another look on it, sorry for bothering you again @Ben Bolker